# How to include a constraint into NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

I have to solve the differential equation, to get a plot of T and R,

```
NDSolve[{R'[T] == (-R[T]/T ) ((1 + Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2])/(1 - 
     Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2])), R[1] == 1}, R, {T, 1, 10}]
```

But it does not work, because I need to eliminate $r$. For this purpose I want to use the following constraint between $r$, $R$ and $T$:

```
-Exp[(-57120.98245600660 ArcTan[3.9669802330201605 (-0.9957452389257688 + 0.268 r)])]/
 ((-0.0317519 + r) (1.96838 - 0.995745 r + 0.134 r^2)^3700.79) + R T == 0
```

How can I get the required result?

Comment: Please provide your question in a form that can be easily pasted into Mathematica.

Comment: @ Oliver Jennrich I have edited the post, please have a look!

Answer (score 5):

You can also solve it as a [DAE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html).  The starting point for

```
Equal @@@ FindRoot[constraint /. T -> 1 /. R[1] -> 1, {r[1], 3.84503}]
```

may be found by plotting.

```
ode = R'[T] == (-R[T]/T) ((1 + Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2]) / 
    (1 - Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2])) /. r -> r[T];
constraint = -Exp[(-57120.98245600660 * 
          ArcTan[3.9669802330201605 (-0.9957452389257688 + 0.268 r)])] / 
        ((-0.0317519 + r) (1.96838 - 0.995745 r + 0.134 r^2)^3700.79) + R T == 
    0 /. {R -> R[T], r -> r[T]};
NDSolve[{
  ode,
  R[1] == 1,
  constraint,
  Equal @@@ FindRoot[constraint /. T -> 1 /. R[1] -> 1, {r[1], 3.84503}]},
 R, {T, 1, 10}]

Plot[R[T] /. sol, {T, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use `ParametericNDSolve` to get a solution that depends parametrically on `r`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{R'[
     T] == (-R[T]/
       T) ((1 + Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2])/(1 - 
         Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2])), R[1] == 1}, 
  R, {T, 1, 10}, {r}]
```

Then you can get a solution for a specific `r` by

```
R1 = R[5] /. sol
```

which can be plotted

```
Plot[R1[T], {T, 1, 10}]
```

Your second condition looks a bit strange, as it will give a solution for 'r' that depends on R[T] which in turn depends on 'r', so this needs some work, I guess.

Comment: @ OliverJennirich It didnt work, output: ReplaceAll::reps: "\!\({ParametricNDSolve[{\*SuperscriptBox[\"R\", \"\[Prime]\",
MultilineFunction->None][T] == \(-\*FractionBox[\(\((1 + \*SqrtBox[\(Plus[<<3>>]\)])\)\\\ R[T]\), \(\((1 + Times[<<2>>])\)\\\ T\)]\), R[1] == 1}, R[r], {T, 1, 10}, {r}]}\) is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"  Please check if I am doing correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can differentiate your constraint, and then include it into your [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call. Here is your constraint (I fixed a syntax error), with `r` replaced with `r[T]`:

```
constraint = -Exp[(-57120.98245600660 ArcTan[3.9669802330201605 (-0.9957452389257688+0.268 r[T])])]/((-0.0317519+r[T]) (1.96838-0.995745 r[T]+0.134 r[T]^2)^3700.79)+R[T] T == 0;
constraint //TeXForm
```

> $T R(T)-\frac{e^{-57120.9824560066` \tan ^{-1}(3.9669802330201605` (0.268` r(T)-0.9957452389257688`))}}{(r(T)-0.0317519`)
>    \left(0.134` r(T)^2-0.995745` r(T)+1.96838`\right)^{3700.79`}}=0$

Differentiate with respect to `T`:

```
dconstraint = D[constraint, T];
dconstraint //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{60728.212622703446` r'(T) e^{-57120.9824560066` \tan ^{-1}(3.9669802330201605` (0.268`
>    r(T)-0.9957452389257688`))}}{\left(15.736932169172686` (0.268` r(T)-0.9957452389257688`)^2+1\right) (r(T)-0.0317519`)
>    \left(0.134` r(T)^2-0.995745` r(T)+1.96838`\right)^{3700.79`}}+\frac{r'(T) e^{-57120.9824560066` \tan
>    ^{-1}(3.9669802330201605` (0.268` r(T)-0.9957452389257688`))}}{(r(T)-0.0317519`)^2 \left(0.134` r(T)^2-0.995745`
>    r(T)+1.96838`\right)^{3700.79`}}+\frac{3700.79` \left(0.268` r(T) r'(T)-0.995745` r'(T)\right) e^{-57120.9824560066` \tan
>    ^{-1}(3.9669802330201605` (0.268` r(T)-0.9957452389257688`))}}{(r(T)-0.0317519`) \left(0.134` r(T)^2-0.995745`
>    r(T)+1.96838`\right)^{3701.79`}}+T R'(T)+R(T)=0$

Your [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call had the initial conditions `T=1` and `R[1]=1`. We can use these initial conditions to determine `r[1]`:

```
r1 = r[1] /. First @ NSolve[(constraint /. {T->1, R[T]->1}) && 0<r[1]<10, r[1]]
```

> 3.84506

Now, we are ready to do the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call (I will use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) instead):

```
{rfunc, Rfunc} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    R'[T] == (-R[T]/T ) ((1 + Sqrt[0.13 r[T]^3 + 2 r[T] - (0.5)^2])/(1 - Sqrt[0.13 r[T]^3 + 2 r[T] - (0.5)^2])),
    R[1] == 1,
    dconstraint,
    r[1] == r1
    },
    {r, R},
    {T, 1, 10}
];
```

*(Note that one could have also used just constraint above, but the initial condition `r[1]==r1` would still be needed because `NDSolveValue` is unable determine the initial condition)* And a plot of `Rfunc`:

```
Plot[Rfunc[t], {t, 1, 10}, AxesLabel->{"T", "R"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know what changed in the past 2 years, but in v12.0.0 the above code fails for numerical underflow and complex infinity errors.  To get the `r1` expression you show above to work at all, I had to explicitly use `SetPrecision` and make the precision huge.  I've tried similar tricks in `NDSolveValue` in addition to adding a Method and SolveDelayed option set to true, but to no avail.  Thoughts?